# How to update Microsoft Access database to Visual Basic dataset after adding new items

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access-2010, updating

I've just started making my first program that uses a database with Visual Basic and I've come across a small glitch with my code. This program takes names of people and a few other fields of information and puts them onto a database file called AddressBook.mdb. I have a few buttons that do various things including moving between each record and updating changes to the current record. My issue though is with adding a new entry.
The button itself works when I use it, the only issue is that after saving I cannot view the new entry in the application until I've restarted it.

Here is the code for the commit button that saves the current data as a new entry:

```
Private Sub btnCommit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCommit.Click
    If inc <> -1 Then

        Dim cb As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
        Dim dsNewRow As DataRow

        dsNewRow = ds.Tables("AddressBook").NewRow()

        dsNewRow.Item("FirstName") = txtFirstName.Text
        dsNewRow.Item("Surname") = txtSurname.Text
        dsNewRow.Item("SSN") = ssn.Text
        dsNewRow.Item("DOB") = dob.Text
        dsNewRow.Item("Weight") = weight.Text
        dsNewRow.Item("Height") = tall.Text
        dsNewRow.Item("Phone") = phone.Text
        dsNewRow.Item("Address1") = address.Text
        dsNewRow.Item("City") = city.Text
        dsNewRow.Item("Postcode") = zip.Text
        dsNewRow.Item("Hair") = hair.Text
        dsNewRow.Item("Eye") = eye.Text
        dsNewRow.Item("Gender") = gender.Text

        ds.Tables("AddressBook").Rows.Add(dsNewRow)

        da.Update(ds, "AddressBook")

        MsgBox("New Record added to the Database")

        btnCommit.Enabled = False
        btnAddNew.Enabled = True
        btnUpdate.Enabled = True
        btnDelete.Enabled = True

    End If
End Sub
```

Is there something I can do to update the dataset after the button is clicked so that I might view the new entry right after making it?

Answer (score 0):

If i remember, there is a Refresh method available.

Worst case scenario, do a manual refresh by destroying the object and recreating.

I think its personally just easier to just recreate the object, cause refreshing (manually or automated) requires you to compare values and do an update on the DataSet.

Based on your notation, it looks like this is a desktop app, so refreshing with a new DataSet will have very little effect on the application.